# Is it necessary to learn php in order to use drupal to manage my site?

Tags: 7

I am planning on using Drupal to manage a website. Should I learn PHP because I understand Drupal is built on PHP language?

I don't know PHP and I am not planning to learn it, but I have decided to use Drupal as my CMS, will I still efficiently manage my geospatial data handling site?

Comment: Drupal has a well built admin interface using which you could manage and create most of the site. You might need to learn php if you want to granular customizations for which you might end up writing a custom module of your own.

Comment: All depends on what you plan to do. If you would ask more precise questions, you could get better response here.

Comment: Hi, please don't fundamentally change a question once it's been answered. It invalidates existing answers and just isn't what we do here. If you have extra information, _add_ it to the question rather than removing the original intent. I've rolled back the changes. Thanks

Comment: There's plenty of modules that can be used from a GUI, and you'll be able to do most things with that. The difficulty is, when a module provides 95% of the functionality you want, and the remaining 5% are really important to you. Then someone needs to implement the those 5%. Of course, you can always pay someone for that.

Comment: If my comment suggested that radical edit, then I'm sorry. I only wanted to provide explanation, not suggest a course of action.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not "necessary". Drupal core has a UI to perform its basic functions, as do most contributed modules.

Beyond that, it's totally up to ***you*** to say whether you need to learn PHP, based on the level of customisation ***you*** need in your site

If all the functionality you'll ever need can be provided through the UI of whatever modules you decide to use, then no, you won't need to learn PHP. If all of that functionality *isn't* provided "out-of-the-box", then yes, you'll need to learn PHP.

As with anything, your mileage will vary. The only possible way to answer this question properly is for you to get stuck in and try it out for yourself.